# Is there a way to get the table details tab meta data from bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, metadata

I want to pull the meta data found in the details tab of BigQuery tables into a query.  This contains labels, row counts, description, clusters, partition and other very useful information to the table.  The labels alone contain information in our case that connects MDM and governance details.  These are added at build time, but struggling to be able to query.

I'm aware of the `information_schema.tables` and `information_schema.columns` views.  That has good info too, but not the items above.  What I am looking for are all the meta-data items contained in the "details" tab when browsing the BigQuery tables visually through the console.

The details tab looks something like this:

[image: table details tab in GCP]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably worth checking out https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-intro for the list of views.  I'm guessing what you're after is in some combination of the `TABLE_OPTIONS` view and/or the various storage views.